# Checkout specific ref in Azure Pipeline from private GitHub

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm facing a problem when trying to use a parameter in my resources.

```
parameters:
- name: MyVersion
  default: "0.0.0"

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: other
    type: github
    name: mycompany/project
    #Ref with parameter is not allowed
    ref: refs/tags/tag_${{parameters.MyVersion}}
    endpoint: mygithub
```

While [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72400534/checkout-different-repository-as-per-input-in-azure-pipeline) could potentially help, it doesn't work for me because I'm using GitHub.   How do I do the same thing with GitHub?

I tried

```
- checkout: git://mycompany/project@refs/tags/tag_${{parameters.MyVersion}}
```

But it tells me "mycompany" doesn't exist.  Which makes sense because mycompany is on GitHub and not in Azure DevOps.   How do I help Azure DevOps find it?   Also, this is a private project that requires authentication for checkout.

Comment: Look at this link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @M Karimi's suggestion in comments I ended up doing a manual checkout from github with PAT

```
  - checkout: none
  - script: |
    git clone https://$(GITHUBPAT)@github.com/mycompany/project.git
    git checkout refs/tags/tag_${{parameters.MyVersion}}
```